# How to copy a file from "folder" A, to folder B on the same Bucket using a Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

thanks a lot.

I know, that S3 doesn't have a folders. But I have a prefix, abcabc/Pdf and abcabc/BackUpPdf.
The problem is, when the client upload a file to the prefix abcabc/Pdf a Lambda is trigered to copy this file to abcabc/BackUpPdf. I'm using boto3

Here is a part of my code in the Lambda, in key is saved the source file path

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)    
    print('Inside the function')
    

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    
    print('Bucket: ' + bucket + ', Key: ' + key)
    
    client.Object(bucket, 'abcabc/BackUpPdf/TestFile.pdf').copy_from(CopySource = key, ACL='public-read')
```

The trouble is, Im getting a ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied. I thought it was because of the IAM role, so I put S3FullAccess to the Lamda role but i still have the same problem. Looking for in a different forums, I found that you can edit a policy for the bucket like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

In fact, there was a mistake. It worked, once I changed the way of the instruction like this:

```
client.Object(bucket, 'abcabc/BackUpPdf/TestFile.pdf').copy_from(CopySource = bucket + '/' + key)
```

Additionally, the Block all public access are enabled in the Bucket

Comment: Does your bucket have [Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) enabled? That would prevent an object being stored with a `public-read` ACL.

Comment: @jarmod Initially it was enabled, I disabled it and the result is the same

Comment: If you are using an AWS Lambda function to copy objects within a bucket owned by the same AWS Account as the Lambda function, then you definitely do not need to use a Bucket Policy, nor do you need to turn off Block Public Access. Granting permissions in the IAM Role associated with the function will be fully sufficient. So, is the S3 bucket owned by the same AWS Account as the Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the Lamda and the Bucket are owned by the same account. Testing, the role has two policies: S3FullAccess and LambdaBasicExecution Role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be passing the `CopySource` parameter to [copy_from](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=Object#S3.Object.copy_from) incorrectly. You can pass a string, which should be of the form:

```
CopySource: `{bucket}/{key}`
```

Or you can pass a dict such as:

```
CopySource: {'Bucket': 'bucket', 'Key': 'key'}
```

You seem to be passing the string `{key}` rather than `{bucket}/{key}`. I'd recommend the dict option over the string option.

Another possible reason is that you have S3 [Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) enabled. That would prevent an object being stored with a `public-read` ACL. Note: Block Public Access can be enabled at account level or at bucket level.

Comment: I'm not sure but in the bucket, the Block all public access
are disabled. But i'me getting the same exception.

Comment: @CarlosQuiñones If you updated your code as jarmod explained, then please Edit your question to show the current code that you are using, and the current error message. (You can add it at the end of your question rather than replacing the existing question.)